# Select last records before find some field value

Tags: mysql

How can I get the last(talking about datetime) records from a table before find some field value?
If I have this table:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+-----------+
| id | date                |  flag | data      |
+----+---------------------+-------------------+
|  1 | 2008-09-01 15:02:00 |   1   | ....    . |
|  2 | 2008-09-01 16:15:00 |   5   | ....    . |
|  3 | 2008-09-01 16:19:00 |   4   | ....    . |
|  4 | 2008-09-01 16:20:00 |   4   | ....    . |
|  5 | 2008-09-01 16:20:00 |   5   | ....    . |
|  6 | 2008-09-01 18:18:00 |   9   | ....    . |
+----+---------------------+-------+-----------+
```

I want to get the last records before find "4" flag field value, I mean:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE..... ORDER BY id DESC

+----+---------------------+-------+-----------+
| id | date                |  flag | data      |
+----+---------------------+-------------------+
|  5 | 2008-09-01 18:18:00 |   9   | ....    . |
|  4 | 2008-09-01 16:20:00 |   5   | ....    . |
+----+---------------------+-------+-----------+
```

How can I get it?
Added: Additionally I would know how get the records with the first occurrence of "4" included
Added: The flag field doesn't have ordered values
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify. What do you mean "the last record before a '4' flag value?"  This implies an order to your records.  Are you ordering by `id` value? Are your id values guaranteed to be consecutive without gaps? What do you want to happen with the record right before the second flag 4 in your example (that is, record 3). It is right before a record with flag 4, even though it has a flag 4 itself.

Comment: It's probably helpful to explain what your application is trying to do.

Comment: Yeah thanks, posted a better explanation about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ID are always ordered, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE id>(SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable WHERE flag="4")
```

or you could use the datetime field:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE
  date>=(SELECT MAX(date) FROM mytable WHERE flag="4")
  AND flag!="4"
```

and the records with the firs occurrence of "4":

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE date=(SELECT MIN(date) FROM mytable WHERE flag="4")
```

Answer (score 2):

So since it is about descending order, just do:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE flag>4 ORDER BY id DESC
```

About your 'addition' - there's no *'first'* record in terms of SQL since they all are equal when we're speaking of order. I.e. you should first specify order inside same `flag` values, then you'll be able to determine which row is first.

*Based on comments*

If we're speaking about ordering with `date` field, that will be:

1) Get all records with `date` field greater than maximum `date` for `4`-flag row:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  mytable 
WHERE 
  `date`>(SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM mytable WHERE flag=4) 
  AND 
  flag!=4
```

2) Get all records with `date` field greater than maximum `date` for `4`-flag row and include this row:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  mytable 
WHERE 
  `date`>(SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM mytable WHERE flag=4)
  AND
    flag!=4
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  mytable 
WHERE 
  `date`=(SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM mytable WHERE flag=4) 
  AND 
  flag=4
```

-note, in second case we can't do just `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date>=(SELECT MAX(date) FROM mytable WHERE flag=4)` since there could be rows with `date` field that are same as maximum value for `date` for `4`-flag rows, but with another flag.

Comment: friend if flag will not be in sorted order, what will happen, it will also give upper record

Comment: @developerCK I think OP is telling 'before' in terms of order that was created by `ORDER BY` clause. In this case, order is descending, so we should use `>` comparison

Comment: The flag field could be any value, your answer don't apply

Comment: @Goku I'm lost. You've pointed exact value in your question. Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry if I don't explain it enough.. updated the Question with the note.

Comment: Then it's even more twisty now. What does it mean 'any value'?

Comment: Ok, I added some better for the case.

Comment: SO, now ot makes more sense -still I need to know. Do you mean 'last X before' - i.e. `5` and `9` were chosen since their timestamps are later than timestamp of maximum `4`-flag row?

Comment: @Goku this is very different. You first step should was mention that in question. See my edit then

Comment: yeah, that because I save my question before finish the edition..Sorry